# scrollLeft can be changed by "click" event but not "mousewheel" event

Tags: javascript, mousewheel

So basically I've made a custom element which do something like this:

```
var target = document.getElementById(self.getAttribute("for"));

self.querySelector(":scope > main:first-child").addEventListener("click", function () {
    target.scrollLeft -= 400;
});

self.querySelector(":scope > main:last-child").addEventListener("click", function () {
    target.scrollLeft += 400;
});

target.addEventListener("mousewheel", function (e) {
    if (e.wheelDelta < 0) {
        target.scrollLeft += 400;
    } else {
        target.scrollLeft -= 400;
    }
});
```

Generally speaking, there're two main elements in this custom element, as long as a "for" attribute. When you click the main element, the element specified by "for" will scroll horizontally. The same thing SHOULD happen while you scroll your mousewheel. However, the main elements work fine, while the mouse scrolling keep failing.

I made several console log to track stuff. While the mousewheel event get correctly fired, the target.scrollLeft is always 0. Always lock down to 0. And again, it changed correctly by the "click" event.

This weird issue has been bothering me for days, anyone knows why? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I missed the e.preventDefault() there. After adding it everything works fine.